# User Registration and Authentication/Authorization with MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I need to register users with my AngularJS app. I would like hashing with salt to take place when storing the password into MongoDB. Then I would like the same user to authenticate and authorize for some of the actions he/she could take.

I come from Java/JavaEE background and have never done any registration/authentication/authorization work for a JavaScript app using MEAN stack.

Is there any reference/sample MEAN app I could refer to for understanding registration/authentication/authorization?

Should I be using Cookies or tokens for authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reference/sample MEAN app I could refer to for
>   understanding registration/authentication/authorization?

I preffer [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/). Plugs to express, Supports both Tokens and Cookies, it is easy to work with Angular.js via ajax.

> Should I be using Cookies or tokens for authentication?

Take your own decision, but read [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/) and [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) and [this](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/)

> I come from Java/JavaEE background and

Not clear but if you are new to web development, may be you should read [this excellent post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before)